# Error: KLCalendarView gives error while integrating it into an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

what does these two error means :

**1.** cannot find protocol declaration for 'KLCalendarViewDelegate'

**2.** Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'KLCalendarView'

in this code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KLCalendarView.h"
#import "CheckmarkTile.h"

@interface CalendarTestViewController : UIViewController<KLCalendarViewDelegate> 
{
    KLCalendarView *calendarView;
    KLTile *currentTile;
    UITableView *myTableView;
    NSMutableArray *tableViewData;
    KLTile *tile;
    BOOL shouldPushAnotherView;

}

@end
```

Comment: "error in iphone app" will not help anyone find this post in the future. Edit it to be more descriptive of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Below the import statements add the following statement:

```
@class KLCalendarView;
```

This would definitely solve your Error no. 2

If you have any doubts regarding this then leave a comment below.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey did you try `Clean` and then `Build and Go`? I think this should solve it.

Comment: Hey so did that solve your errors? Or still Error 2nd is not solved?

Comment: @Archana: done but not solve? I am not getting what exactly you are trying to say.

Comment: @parth: means I have follow the steps what u have told(Clean and then Build and Go) but not solve the 2nd error.

Comment: @Archana: Ok fine. Did you check the `KLCalendarView.h` file? Is it completely fine as far as syntax goes?

Comment: @Archana: Did you get a solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of CalendarTestViewController says that it implements KLCalendarViewDelegate, but the compiler says it can't find the declaration for that protocol. The second error makes me think that there's a problem with the declaration of KLCalendarView in KLCalendarView.h, and it may be that's the reason the compiler doesn't see the delegate protocol. Take a careful look at KLCalendarView.h, particularly in the lines above the `@interface KLCalendarView` line. You might find a missing semicolon, missing closing brace, spelling error, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the protocol in your header which your current class will be implementing.

```
A protocol is a list of method declarations. If your class adopts the protocol, 
then you have to implement those methods in your class.
```

So you can declare them as follows:

```
@protocol <name>
<methods>
@end
```